# Get value from JSON data using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

When I alert the results I get following JSON data:

```
var results = JSON.stringify(result.results);
alert(results);

[{
    "test": "Connect_Disconnect222222",
    "jobid": "59",
    "os": "Windows NTeeeeeee",
    "report": "Verify Wireless Interface presenttttttttt and state is Disconnected:OK<br>Verify Profile not present on the Client:OK Client:OK<br>Verify Profile Not Present on the Client:OKffffffffffff<br>"
}]
```

How can I get the values `report`, `test` and `jobid` from that data?

Comment: ``JSON.stringify()`` converts a javascript ``object`` into ``string``, so you won't be able to access those fields anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `result.results` is an array object, so you need to get the first item in the array and then fetch its properties

```
var record = result.results[0];
alert(record.test)
alert(record.jobid)
alert(record.report)
```

Comment: `[ { test: 'Connect_Disconnect222222',
    jobid: '81',
    os: 'Windows NTeeeeeee',
    report: 'Verify Wireless Interface presenttttttttt and state is Disconnected:OK<br>Verify Profile not present on the Client:OK Client:OK<br>Verify Profile Not Present on the Client:OKffffffffffff<br>' } ] from this also`

Comment: what is this object.... if it is the same `result.results` then you can use the same code as above

Comment: `console.log(testDetails[0].results);` prints the above output.from this i have to get test and jobid..i tried`console.log(testDetails[0].results.test);` getting undefined

Comment: you need to use `console.log(testDetails[0].results[0].test);` because the `results` property is an array

Answer (score 0):

When u use `JsonArray` u have to define the row number for example

```
alert(results[0].report);
alert(results[0].test);
alert(results[0].jobid);
```